# Should I keep authentication data in the same table with user data?

Tags: database, game-development

This is for a multiplayer CCG game. User has data for obtained cards, username, user id, accumulated gold etc. while of course having authentication information like email, password, token etc.

I'm not sure if I should keep these data in separate tables because I don't see any cons for doing so but on the other hand it **feels** like they should be in separate tables.

**Is there any pros/cons for these approaches?
and which approach would you use?**